# Prove convergence of $\int^{\pi /2}_{0} \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x}\mathrm dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove convergence of $$\int^{\pi /2}\limits_{0} \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x}\mathrm dx = I$$

Looking for other answers I got that  $$\int\limits_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\ln x\ \mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x}} < I 
<-2\sqrt{2\pi}$$

How conclude from here that  $I$ is convergent? I was mainly looking at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815065/prove-the-convergence-of-integral?noredirect=1).

Edit.

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815065/prove-the-convergence-of-integral?noredirect=1) can you explain why integrand is monotonous and why from that follows convergence?

Comment: Do these answer your question? (1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815065/prove-the-convergence-of-integral?noredirect=1 or (2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313437/convergence-of-definite-integral?noredirect=1

Comment: @User My link is the same as your first linked question.I am asking specific question how continue from there.

Comment: If the integral diverged, then $I$ would be $-\infty$, which is against the inequality.

Comment: Why $I$ would be $-\infty$ if integral diverged? @xpaul

Comment: Use the definition of divergence of improper integrals.

Comment: @xpaul For definition $lim_{c\to b} \int_a ^c f(x)dx$ must be finite. But for that you need to compute $I$ or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Note $$\int_\epsilon^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x}dx$$ is monotone w.r.t $\epsilon\in(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: @xpaul Can you give hints how show that?

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$ I(\epsilon)=\int_\epsilon^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x}dx. $$
Clearly $I(\epsilon)<0$. For $0<\epsilon<\epsilon'<\pi/2$, one has
$$ I(\epsilon)-I(\epsilon')=\int_\epsilon^{\epsilon'}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x}dx \le 0 $$
which implies that $I(\epsilon)$ is increasing in $\epsilon\in(0,\pi/2)$. Then when $\epsilon\to 0^+$, the limit of $I(\epsilon)$ is either finite or $-\infty$.

Comment: Why @xpaul for second inequality there is $\leq$ instead of $<$?